# How to get what are the subscribed events/outputs of an Angular2 component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Currently I'm developing Angular 2 wrapper for jQuery widgets. I want to get list of events subscribed for an `Component`. So that I can only bind that particular events to jQuery widget to avoid unwanted DOM event binding.

I tried to access the HTML attributes from the `ElementRef`, however the properties and events bound with angular2 syntax [input] and (output) are not available in the rendered DOM element.

Anyone have idea of how to get the list of subscribed events of a Component?

Comment: Also I tried to check the `event.observers.length` it is always `1` irrespective of any subscribe to it in application/component level